# Java: Replacing the coffee cup icon in the top-left corner of the Window

Tags: java, swing, installation, icons, window-managers

Java Swing applications by default have the Java coffee cup icon appear in the top left corner of the application.

I would like to replace this with my own image - what API is used?

Can this be done at run time, or must something be done at install time?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [
How do I set an Application's Icon Globally in Swing?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103179/how-do-i-set-an-applications-icon-globally-in-swing) and [
How do I change the default application icon in Java?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209812/how-do-i-change-the-default-application-icon-in-java).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[JFrame.setIconImage(Image image)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage(java.awt.Image)) does exactly that.

Comment: what if I wanted to change the whole application coffe icon instead of just one JFrame?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [setIconImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29) method.

Comment: @camickr It didn't show up as a dup when I posted it... I just found that out now.

Comment: I figured that was the case. When I looked at the question it was answer 14 seconds before I browsed it. The point about a more recent link is another reason why I don't include links to the API. I just point out the method since every programmer should have easy access to the API for whatever version they are using. You can't assume version 5 or 6 is the proper API.