# change icon displayed in title bar for a java desktop app

Tags: java, netbeans, icons, desktop-application, titlebar

I have a Java Desktop Application project created with NetBeans. The icon that is displayed in my main window's titlebar, by default, is the java logo. The same logo is displayed when I minimize this window to the Taskbar.

I would like to change this icon with one specific to my application, but didn't find how.

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched this site for a similar question? In fact many are listed along the right side of this page.  You will find your answer there.

Comment: It is a good idea to become familiar with the JavaDocs instead or relying on your autmagic IDE.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: People tend not to appreciate the ironic part of an advice, but thank you anyway

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels: Actually in the process of posting my question I have been offered some suggestions of similar questions, but they didn't quite match..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at these links:

[how-do-i-change-the-default-application-icon-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209812/how-do-i-change-the-default-application-icon-in-java)
[how-do-i-set-an-applications-icon-globally-in-swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103179/how-do-i-set-an-applications-icon-globally-in-swing)

Comment: Links to other SO answers are more appropriate as comments than as answers themselves.

Comment: Sorry. You are correct, and I will try to comply with this in the future.

Comment: there not possible to change Icon for Java Desktop Application, only j_f_p_o_i_l_p_r_e_t can give us answer for that