# How to set Java aplication name in Unity?

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, jar, ubuntu-unity

I have a Java application, but when I hover over it in the Unity launcher, the name is blank. A similar thing happens in Windows with the name of the window in the taskbar. I pictured the issue in Unity below. Note the empty app name coming from the Java icon. I'm quite new to Java, how do I set the name here? Is it an OS specific thing, or something I forgot to do in the code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see this links. I think that you goes a find your response on this links.

[How can I set the process name for a Java-program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057247/how-can-i-set-the-process-name-for-a-java-program)

[How do I set an Application's Icon Globally in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103179/how-do-i-set-an-applications-icon-globally-in-swing)

Comment: I'm afraid neither of those links were particularly useful…