# .setIconImage(); to all frames instead one by one

Tags: java

How can i set an Icon for all frames that will exist in my application?
I don't want to use `frame.setIconImage(0);
frame1.setIconImage(1);
etc.`
every time i create a frame.

Best Regards,
Marek

Comment: you can extends frames by custom frame

Comment: how exactly i can do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set an Application's Icon Globally in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103179/how-do-i-set-an-applications-icon-globally-in-swing)

Comment: If my main class extends JFrame - do i have to create another subclass? Because if i put `this.setIconImage(Icon);` in my constructor - it doesn't work. @Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a class which extends jframe .

```
public class customFrame extends JFrame{

    public customFrame() {
        try {
            this.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Madhawa.se\\Desktop\\gtg.PNG")));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(customFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}
```

now when you create jframes extends that class[frame] instead jframe.

like follow ;

```
public class frame1 extends customFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new frame1().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

next frame so on..

```
public class frame2 extends customFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new frame2().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

and also you can make frames like follow

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    customFrame frame1 = new customFrame();
    frame1.setTitle("title");
    frame1.add(new JLabel(""));
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: except one thing. Now when i call `customFrame frame = new customFrame("I can't give this title");`

Comment: @jotto Then make another constructor to take the title and call the frames super method...

Comment: @jotto or you can call frame.setTitle("but I can give this title");you should use setters

Comment: getlost, i wanted to get rid of .setIconImage, and now i would have to add .setTitle(); so it would bring more code again. But thank you. You've been very helpful.

Comment: @jotto yes it's better create a constructor so you can easily set title .

Answer (score 0):

While you could extend `JFrame` and create a custom implementation, you're not really adding much new functionality to the frame , which could come, back and haunt you latter.

Another approach would be to create a frame factory, which could be used to generate the frame the way you want it.  This would allow you to create a series of methods to meet your needs.

It also means you can change the way the factory methods work without having to change any of the other code...

```
public class FrameFactory {
    public static JFrame createDefaultFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(...)));
        return frame;
    }

    public static JFrame createFrameWithTitle(String title) {
        JFrame frame = FrameFactory.createDefaultFrame();
        frame.setTitle(title);
        return frame;
    }
}
```